# setInterval does not use updated values of useState variables

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

This is a useEffect function, shopId is updated once, so I assume it run once. even though I call the setOrder function the order variable is not recongnized as updated in here, it is updated in other places.
Is there a way to make the setInterval use the updated order variable?

```
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    if (shopId != null) {
      // console.log(order.length);
      if (order.length == 0) {
        FindCustomer()
          .then((r) => JSON.parse(r))
          .then((r) => {
            console.log(r, "r");
            let col = r["col"];
            setOrder(col);
          });
      }
    }
  }, 10000); // fetch updates every 5 seconds
}, [shopId]);
```

We tried making the setInterval function call a different function, that should check length of order, but got same result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "shopId is updated once, so I assume it run once" that is a *dangerous* assumption. You should store your interval handle and clear it when the component unmounts: `useEffect(() => { const handle = setIterval(...); return () => { clearInterval(handle); } }, [shopId]);` In local dev at least, this will always run **at least 3 times**: twice on the first render pass and once again when you update `shopId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your effect has a dependency on `order` (and technically on `setOrder`), which was omitted from the dependency array.  Add it, so the effect can be updated when that value changes.

You should also **not** assume that the effect will only execute once.  **Especially** if you need it to be updated when a dependency changes.  The effect should return a function which cleans up side effects (e.g. the interval), before it gets invoked again when a dependency changes.

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (shopId != null) {
      // console.log(order.length);
      if (order.length == 0) {
        FindCustomer()
          .then((r) => JSON.parse(r))
          .then((r) => {
            console.log(r, "r");
            let col = r["col"];
            setOrder(col);
          });
      }
    }
  }, 10000); // fetch updates every 5 seconds

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [shopId, order, setOrder]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is, now when we exit the component the setInterval stops running, we would like it to continue

Comment: @Pnina: In that case it shouldn’t be controlled by this component, but by something more root-level (even App). The state could be in a useContext at that level, and nothing else updates it except for this component.  The App-level useEffect can simply not run the interval until that state gets updated to something meaningful.